# How to make react native app to always launch from a specific Screen

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-navigation

I am learning react native and I am stack on how to make the app to always start from a specific `HomeScreen` when app launches or on navigation back. I have a `HomeScreen` that populate `FlatList` from api calls using a custom hook. And would wish the api call to be always called when app launches. And if response code=-1 to always navigate to another screen called `License`. When the `LicenseScreen` pops ups and the user uses the arrow back button to navigate back to `HomeScreen` then app redirect the the initial api call. In short the user should not see the flat list as long as the response code is -1. Here is my code snippet.

```
const AllClient = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { state } = useAuth();
  let [reload, setReload] = useState(true);

  const [loading, data] = useFetchHook(
    //this is a custom hook that uses axios private to fetch data from api
    `/api/customer/all_is_customers/${state?.user?.id}`,
    reload
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setReload(!reload);
    if (data?.code == -1) {
      navigation.navigate("license"); //I want to navigate to License Screen every time user launch the application
    } else {
      setCustomers(data?.obj);
    }
  }, [loading, data]);

  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState(data?.obj); //to be used in my flatlist
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        className="flex-1 mb-3"
        data={customers}
        renderItem={({ item }) =>
          customers.includes(item) ? <CustomerRow customer={item} /> : null
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional rendering screens instead of navigating. Show loading state while resolving the route asynchronously and after resolved set the desired route. Something like this:

```js
const [route, setRoute] = useState(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
...
  // TODO API call
  setRoute("Home") // Set state according to result 
...
}, [])

return !route ? (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <ActivityIndicator />
  </View>
) : (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {route == 'Home' ? (
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      ) : (
        <Stack.Screen name="License" component={LicenseScreen} />
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

See [Authentication flows](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow) for more information about conditional rendering.

Comment: My api calls are made from home screen not app.js